# Specify Level for particular class

Tags: java, log4j

If I need to set threshold on package level to `INFO` I can make setup for my package `MyPck` like:

```
log4j.logger.MyPck=INFO,debugLogFile
```

I it possible to make threshold not on package, but on class level? Something like :

```
log4j.logger.MyPck.MyClass=INFO,debugLogFile
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is *Yes*.

---

However, by default, each logger inherits the attributes of its *parent*. e.g.:

Consider the simple Java class:

```
package com.abc;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

class AnotherClass {
    private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(AnotherClass.class);
    public AnotherClass() {
        LOG.trace("Instance created of AnotherClass");
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
    public MyClass() {
        LOG.trace("Instance created of MyClass");
    }
    public void foo() {
        LOG.info("Executing foo()...");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyClass().foo();
        new AnotherClass();
    }
}
```

And the `log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout

log4j.logger.com.abc=TRACE,STDOUT
log4j.logger.com.abc.MyClass=INFO,STDOUT
```

In the example, `STDOUT` is configured into the logger `com.abc`. So, `com.abc.MyClass` inherited and writes to *that* object. See the output:

```
INFO - Executing foo()...
INFO - Executing foo()...
TRACE - Instance created of AnotherClass
```

What's going on? Why two times? The property `additivity` can prevent this propagation.

```
log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout

log4j.logger.com.abc=TRACE,STDOUT
log4j.logger.com.abc.MyClass=INFO,STDOUT
log4j.additivity.com.abc.MyClass=false
```

So, we will see:

```
INFO - Executing foo()...
TRACE - Instance created of AnotherClass
```